# JavaScript function undefined from console no visible response

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jsonp

I've got this function in the body of my jQuery Mobile page:

```
    <script>
        function theManufacturers(inputSearch){
            var qryString = 0;
            
            //set up string for adding <li/>
            var li = "";
            var jqxhr = $.getJSON("http://someurl.com/page.aspx?sumvar=hello&callback=?",
            function(data){
                    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
                        li += '<li><a href="#" id="' + i + '" class="info-go">' + item.Manufacturer + '</a></li>';
                    });
                    $("#manufacturer-list").append(li);
                    $("#manufacturer-list").listview("refresh");
                });
            //jqxhr.done(function() {
             //   console.log( "second success" );
            //});
        };
    </script>
```

I've tried calling it form the console in Firebug and the command just turn blue and then the line underneath in grey says "undefined". And obviously the function doesn't appear to be doing anything.

Comment: It should be returning undefined since you're not returning anything.

Comment: It's correct that it returns `undefined`. If you're not seeing the page get updated, then either A) The JSONP call is failing, or B) There are no entries in `data.items`. Use your debugger to find out which (there's a fully-featured debugger built into your browser).

Comment: Do you have an error with the JSONP call? Does the resource you are calling actually return JSONP?

Comment: Why `var jqxhr`? Just run `$.getjson()` directly.

Comment: If you don't explicitly return something, JavaScript functions return undefined. Your function seems to operate not by providing a return but by side effects. When I run this function in console, it runs the get request to the URL you provide but since it is not a valid URL, an error appears in console.

Comment: @BillCriswell Ah ok, so that essentially saying its working but it has no value to return? Which in this case is the expected result..?

Comment: Yes. I'd follow @T.J.Crowder's debugging tips.

Comment: @Omar Just because I was toying around with the ability to do something on success, as you'll see from the commented out jqxhr.done.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Good suggestions thanks. I guess the undefined response in the console through me a little.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Will do thanks for the responses / clarity.

Comment: @BillCriswell If you want to post that as an answer I'll happily accept it. Thanks.

Comment: I think @T.J.Crowder should be the one who gets the credit. His advice is way more helpful than my answer.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It seems the honours are yours. If you want to put an answer up, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @BillCriswell Very honourable Sir!

Comment: @PhillHealey: Good man, but I think it was more a direction toward an answer than an answer. If you find the actual answer (there was an error, or the array had no entries), go ahead and post it and, after the 48-hour limit, accept it. Glad to have helped,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by T.J.Crowder & Bill Crisswell, the undefined response was to be expected and is doesn't actually suggest anything wrong with my JS function.

The actual problem was that I'd copied the code across from another page in the project and hadn't updated the references to the correct listview in my JS. Hence the listview on the page wasn't being populated with the resultant data pulled in by the function.

At least I learned that the undefined console response was the correct output for my JS, and I now know why. Thanks to everyone who pointed this out.